# Analytics and traffic analysis of user created programs

Tags: pyrocms

I have a website developed in PyroCMS, In which registered users can create programs . I want to provide a traffic analysis tool for monitoring clicks to these programs. So that user can signed in and check analytic.

How can I do this ? Is their any module available ? or any suggestion for approach ?

Thanks, Janan